# Radio button with Immeditate action using NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have created customize page with two radio button for repair and remove.If the user select the repair button it goes for repair fun.but again come to old page that is repair and remove page.so the user selects both option.My requirement is user selects only one option and do corresponding actions only.No need to give the option to select both the buttons.

```
     Function nsDialogpage
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
       Abort
    ${EndIf}
    ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
    Pop $Repair
    ${NSD_AddStyle} $Repair ${WS_GROUP}
    ${NSD_OnClick} $Repair Repair 
    ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
    Pop $Remove
    ${NSD_OnClick} $Remove Remove
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
Function Repair
-- Do repair function.
FunctionEnd
Function Remove
   ExecWait "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"
   Quit
FunctionEnd
```

also if remove fun have remove the installer and quit the installation.
uninstaller has been done successfully.but installer again go main page after that user click any button then only  quit from installation steps.

1.User select any one option and leave this repair and remove page.

2.If user click remove option remove the installer and immediately quit the process.

Comment: Please post more code...

Comment: What do you mean by leave the repair page (1)? Do you want it to go to the next page or quit?

Comment: If the user select the repair button go to the repair functionality and do the next page progress.In my case if user selects repair option its goes for repair page and again .its comes to nsDialogpage page.then only go for next page.I think this is not good installer.

Answer (score 0):

Quit does not quit right away when used in a page action callback, it will quit when the page changes. Performing some action when a radio button is clicked is not normal Windows behavior (Try pressing TAB) so I added a normal example aswell.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom RepairOrRemovePageInsane_Create
Page Custom RepairOrRemovePageNormal_Create RepairOrRemovePageNormal_Leave
Page InstFiles

Function Remove
ExecWait '"cmd" /C echo This is a dummy uninstall command...&pause' ; Call real uninstaller here
FunctionEnd

Function Repair
# Do repair....
FunctionEnd

Function RepairOrRemovePageInsane_Create
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
Pop $0
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_NEXTDLGCTL} $0 1
${NSD_OnClick} $0 RepairInsane
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
Pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 RemoveInsane
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1 ; Get Next button handle and
EnableWindow $0 0 ; ...disable it because it does not make sense with this insane radio button handling
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function RemoveInsane
Call Remove
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0 
FunctionEnd

Function RepairInsane
Call Repair
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 1 0 ; Go to next page
FunctionEnd

Function RepairOrRemovePageNormal_Create
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $1
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 5u 100% 10u "Repair"
Pop $1
${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 25u 100% 56u "Remove"
Pop $2
SendMessage $1 ${BM_CLICK} 0 0 ; Select one of them by default
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function RepairOrRemovePageNormal_Leave
${NSD_GetState} $1 $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    Call Repair
${Else}
    Call Remove
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```